# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have written code as below for return list using class as below

```
 public class UsersModel
    {
        public List<CaseValues> CaseDetails { get; set; }
        public CaseValues GetCasedetails(string userName)
        {
            using (var cases = new RassiEntities())
            {
                CaseDetails = (from list in cases.Accidents
                               join users in cases.aspnet_Users on list.LockedBy equals users.UserId
                               select new CaseValues
                               {
                                   CaseId = list.caseid
                               }).ToList();
            }
            return CaseDetails ;
        }
    }

    public class CaseValues
    {
        public int CaseId { get; set; }
    }
```

Please share your suggestion.

Comment: You want to return a *list* of items, yet your return type is a single value. That's what the message says too

Comment: what do you want to return, a single object or a list of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method returns **`List<CaseValues>`**, so the signature should be,

```
 public List<CaseValues>  GetCasedetails(string userName)
```

Comment: Its Worked for me .. Thanks @sajeetharan

Comment: I need to store this return values in CaseValues is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Change the return type.

```
public List<CaseValues> GetCasedetails(string userName)
```

or change the return value to single object of CaseValues like below code

```
return CaseDetails.FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this will help